# Matlab-Index in position 1 is invalid. Array indices must be positive integers or logical values

Tags: function, matlab, indexing

i am pretty new to Matlab and i recently met this issues :-Index in position 1 is invalid. Array indices must be positive integers or logical values.

```
beta_1 = beta(WMT,RF,SP500)';
beta_2 = beta(SBUX,RF,SP500)';
beta_3 = beta(MSFT,RF,SP500)';
beta_4 = beta(JPM,RF,SP500)';
beta_5 = beta(IBM,RF,SP500)';
beta_6 = beta(HD,RF,SP500)';
beta_7 = beta(DIS,RF,SP500)';
beta_8 = beta(BP,RF,SP500)';
beta_9 = beta(BA,RF,SP500)';
beta_10= beta(NIKE,RF,SP500)';


my function: 
function [beta_temp] = beta(stockdata,riskfree, marketdata)
beta_temp = zeros(60,0);
for i = 1:60
    temp_stock = stockdata(i:i+59,1);
    temp_rf = riskfree(i:i+59,1);
    temp_mkt = marketdata(i:i+59,1);
    rif = temp_stock - temp_rf;
    rmf = temp_mkt - temp_rf;
    
    model = regress(rif,rmf);
    beta_temp(i)= model;
end     
end
```

Comment: I suspect you didn't really want a 60 by 0 matrix. `beta_temp = zeros(60,0);`